# How to reference one value to various cells, depending on a date?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please have a look at the picture I attached, it'll make understanding my problem easier because it's hard to describe.

In the first table, I have capacity data for a product. The capacity changes by the date indicated in the column, i.e. from July 2017 the capacity would be 56, from December 2018 78, and from October 2019 99. The reason why I don't write down the capacity for every month is that I want to save columns.

In the second table, I have every month. I want to reference the correct capacity for each month, e.g. it would be 56 for every month until December 2018.

I have been considering an =INDEX function, but it seems to complex for that. Is there a way to reference like this without using VBA? Would the VBA solution be simple? Or am I forced to write a column for every month's capacity in the first table? Thank you!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xl7R.png
[image: Capacity Problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use several IF statements to compare the month in your column with the months given in your first table, and put the value of the correponding month.

Let's admit your first row is 1 and first column is A, it should give something like:

```
= IF(D7>=$F$2; $F$3; IF(D7 >= $E$2; $E$3; IF(D7 >= $D$2; $D$3; "")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont see you columns and rows so i hope you will change them correctly on this formula:

=HLOOKUP(C111,$C$106:$P$107,2,TRUE)

- C111 is the cell above your red row.
- $C$106:$P$107 is the tableof capacities, i know it is bigger then the current one so you see you can add more columns.
- 2 is the row number from the capacity table.
- true is becouse you dont want it to be the exact value it will take the previews in hte order of items

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers work perfectly, but I would go this way-
You don't actually need an if to find the previous capacity. you can simply use the approximate match (similar to the hlookup answer) in an index formula

```
=+INDEX($B$4:$E$5,MATCH($B$9,$B$4:$B$5,0),MATCH(C9,$B$4:$E$4,1))
```

The product $B$9 matches exact (0), but the date C9 is bigger than or equal (1).

$B$4:$E$5 is the source of capacity and 
C9:AF9 the date timeline

Final advantage would be that you can have several products to index, not only a single one.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will keep this in mind once I need to deal with several products:)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the below formula and provide feedback please?

```
=IF(AND(D8>=D2,D8<E2),"56",IF(AND(D8>=E2,D8<F2),"78",IF(D8>=F2,"99")))
```